# How to write a regular expression to replace dots and single spaces inside of a string in Teradata?

Tags: regex, teradata

I am badly in need to write a regular expression which replaces dots or single spaces inside of particular sub strings in a string. Suppose the string that I want to parse is something like 'AB.C$. WFD.C!-' . Now the reg ex should essentially convert it to 'ABC$. WFD.C!-' i.e. if a space and dot comes in between AB and C or precede or succeed them then only they should be replaced. Please help me through .

Comment: I do not want to replace case by case scenarios like 'AB.c.' or 'AB c.' or 'AB c ' to 'ABc'. I desperately want it to be done via reg ex. Please explain me the steps also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('AB.C$. WFD.C!-', 'A(\.| )B', 'AB', 1, 0, 'c');`

It will remove all literal dots and spaces between `A` and `B` starting at position 1 in the input string, and will replace *all* occurrences (`0` argument),
and `'c'` means case sensitive matching.

Read more about the [teradata regex syntax here](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/Regular_Expr_Functions.085.10.html).